# Gnuplot - Tabular key/legend

Tags: gnuplot

Current command `set key left Left vertical maxrows 6`. This makes the overall form tabular (as I want).

[image: Current "tabular key"]

What I actually want is something like:

```
|Nucl. Calc. Exp.|
|Kr  dot+line  x |
|Rb  dot+line  x |
|Sr  dot+line  x |
|Y   dot+line  x |
|Zr  dot+line  x |
|Mo  dot+line  x |
```

So there are two things that I need to do: 1. Make a key entry for the `x` without a title (i.e. get rid of the "exp" but `notitle`/`""` doesn't work) and 2. Somehow make three headings for the columns.

For making the column headings, I can think up of using labels as a inelegant solution by positioning them appropriately but I think there must be some feature built in for this but I'm not able to grasp it.

The bounding box I've drawn in the requirement is unimportant/easily do-able.

Edit: I forgot to mention I'm using the `pngcairo dashed` terminal.

Comment: Try with a space character, `title " "`, but then the space between line and dot is probably too large. Or you could try the `lua tikz` terminal, which gives you better control for such finetuning.

Comment: I did not think of using other terminals. Sorry I forgot to mention the `pngcairo dashed` terminal in the question. Added it now. I'll have a look at `lua tikz`.

Comment: I just checked: the `" "` creates way too much space.